# What does the expression $ww^*$ for any vector $w$ mean?

Tags: matrices

- My Question:

Currently I'm reading the german textbook "Grundlagen der Numerischen Mathematik und des Wissenschaftlichen Rechnens" from Hanke-Bourgeois. On page 247 he describes a devide-and-conquer-method for computing the eigenvalues of a hermetic tridiagonal matrix using this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l33ha.jpg) and the definitions $\gamma_{m-1} = \alpha_m - \beta_m$ and $\gamma_m = \alpha_{m+1} - \beta_m$.

He then defines $w = e_m + e_{m+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and explains that the matrix decomposition shown in the picture can also be expressed as $A = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
A_1 & 0 \\                                              
0 & A_2 \\                                              
\end{array}\right] + \beta_m w w^* $.

I am very sure that $\beta_m w w^*$ represents the second summand in the decomposition, namely $\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
& & & \\
 & \beta_m & \beta_m & \\                                              
 & \beta_m & \beta_m & \\ 
& & & \\                                            
\end{array}\right]$, but I don't understand how this matrix is actually represented by $\beta_m w w^*$.

- My Assumptions:

$w = e_m + e_{m+1}$ is the sum of two unit vectors and $w^*$ is probably the transpose of $w$. Now, by the same notation as in the textbook, the matrix $C = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
& & & \\
 & 1 & 1 & \\                                              
 & 1 & 1 & \\ 
& & & \\                                            
\end{array}\right]$, where every entry is $0$ except $c_{m,m} = c_{m+1,m} = c_{m,m+1} = c_{m+1,m+1} = 1 $, can be represented by $w w^*$. Now I always thought of $ww^*$ to be the dot product represented by the matrix multiplication:

$ww^* = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\                                              
w_3 \\
...                                            
\end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & ... \\                                  
\end{array}\right] = w \cdot w \in \mathbb{R}$

This doesn't make any sense because of $ww^* = C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: You've miscalculated the matrix product: an $n\times 1$ matrix times a $1\times n$ matrix is $n\times n$, so $(ww^\ast)_{ij}=w_iw^\ast_j$. Actually, if we denote complex conjugation with $^\ast$, the conjugate transpose of $w$ should really be denoted $w^\dagger$ instead of $w^\ast$, viz. $w^\dagger=w^{T\ast}=w^{\ast T}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

- $w$ is a column vector : $w = [w_1,\cdots,w_n]^T$
- $w^*$ is conjugate transpose of $w$

Then : $ww^*$ will be the self-outer product:

$$ww^* =\begin{bmatrix}w_{1}{w_1}^* & w_1 {w_2}^* & \cdots &w_1 {w_n}^*\\w_2{w_1}^* &\ddots&\cdots &w_2{w_n}^*\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\w_n{w_1}^*&\cdots&\cdots &w_n {w_n}^*\end{bmatrix}$$

But as you note, if $w$ instead is a row vector, then it will be a self-inner product.

So it depends on how the vectors are defined : As row or column vectors.